# The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly

Tags: wcf

Following is the service model configuration in my web.config file:

```
    <system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior>
        <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IDataPortal" closeTimeout="01:00:00" openTimeout="01:00:00" receiveTimeout="01:00:00" sendTimeout="01:00:00"
       allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="true" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
       maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="65536" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
       textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true" messageEncoding="Text">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="64" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="4096"
                      maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
        <security mode="None">
          <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""></transport>
          <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
        </security>
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <client>
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:4481/MyDataService.svc"
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IDataPortal"
              name="BasicHttpBinding_IDataPortal"
              contract="eBusiness_Core.Contracts.ServiceContracts.IBusinessData">
    </endpoint>
  </client>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

When I check execution of WCF methods in WCF Test Client, it executes the call, but in the end it returns an exception saying "The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly."
I have used custom types in my WCF service, and I have decorated them with "DataContract" and "Serializable" both attributes.
When I check a simple method returning string, it works fine.
What could be the reason?

Comment: This is most likely a deserialization issue. Your configuration is not important in this situation. Your "custom classes" are. So maybe You can show them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This started working fine and perfect after upgrading the POCO generator classes to use EF 5.0